# I need help about a specific query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck in a question and I can not create the structure of query in my mind. Could you give me an idea to where to start about following question:

List the data(neptuncode, lecturer, number of students registered) of those subjects for which a maximum of 2 students have registered ever(dont forget about subjects for which no one has ever registered)

My tables are;

```
ENROLLMENTS
ENROLLMENT_ID   NUMBER(10,0)    No
SUBJECT NUMBER(10,0)    Yes
STUDENT NUMBER(10,0)    Yes
ENROLLMENTDATE  DATE    No
FIRSTENROLL NUMBER(1,0) No
PARITY  NVARCHAR2(4 CHAR)   No
EXAMDATE    DATE    No

STUDENTS 
STUDENT_ID  NUMBER(10,0)
NEPTUNCODE  NVARCHAR2(6 CHAR)
NAME    NVARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
ADDRESS NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
DATEOFBIRTH DATE
ENTRANCEYEAR    NUMBER(4,0)

SUBJECTS
SUBJECT_ID  NUMBER(10,0)
NEPTUNCODE  NVARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
SUBJECTNAME NVARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
LECTURER    NVARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
DAY1    NVARCHAR2(2 CHAR)
DAY2    NVARCHAR2(2 CHAR)
ROOM    NVARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
```

[image: tables]

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, COUNT(), HAVING

Comment: Could you be more specific, i could not construct the query

Answer (score 1):

I would structure the SQL as an inline view to count the enrollments, using a `HAVING` clause to limit the count to `2`. Then I would use a `LEFT JOIN` on the inline view to ensure that subjects with no enrollments get `enrollment_count` of `NULL`. Finally, the `NVL` function (Oracle only. For other databases, try `COALESCE`) is used to default any `NULL` values to `0`.
Your question doesn't require the use of the `STUDENTS` table, because it is only concerned with counting the enrollments.

Here's the code:

```
SELECT
s.neptuncode,
s.lecturer,
NVL(enr.enrollment_count,0) AS enrollment_count
FROM subjects s
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
              e.subject_id,
              COUNT(*) AS enrollment_count
              FROM enrollments e
              GROUP BY e.subject_id
              HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
          ) enr ON enr.subject = s.subject_id;
```

Comment: Oracle also has `coalesce()`.

Comment: According to the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617), `COALESCE` is a generalization of the `NVL` function. Yes, it can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a `GROUP BY` in combination with `HAVING`. I'm not sure what "NEPTUNCODE" is - not sure what your key relationships are here but see if this might work.

EDIT: Updated based on keys image added to question.

```
SELECT SUBJECTS.NEPTUNCODE, 
       SUBJECTS.LECTURER, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID) STUDENTS
FROM SUBJECTS 
  LEFT JOIN ENROLLMENTS ON ENROLLMENTS.SUBJECT = SUBJECTS.SUBJECT_ID
  LEFT JOIN STUDENTS ON ENROLLMENTS.STUDENT = STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID
GROUP BY SUBJECTS.NEPTUNCODE, SUBJECTS.LECTURER
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID) <= 2
```

Comment: I have added an IMAGE below the my question about the keys, could you check it because last thing did not go well. You can check it from the link. @MichaelTallino

Comment: @gokaydogan Check it now - Basically - make a query that pulls what you want including Student IDs and then just change the STUDENT_ID to count (like in my example) and add GROUP BY for all selected columns (except the aggregated one obvs) and the HAVING line is what decides what your cutoff is

Comment: I actually created a code however I can not exclude NULL values, in other words, even if nobody is registered for a course, numbers seems as 1 since use COUNT(*)
YOU CAN CHECK MY UPDATED ANSWER